# Listen to Event : User::creating

Tags: laravel, events, octobercms

I'm doing a new plugin for OctoberCms. I would like to limit the front end registration for some specific domains.

I tried to this :

```
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
[......]
    public function boot()
    {
        // Listen for user creation
        Event::listen('eloquent.creating:  October\Rain\Auth\Models\User', function($model) {
        {
            $this->checkDomains($user);
            [.....]
        }
    }
}
```

But my listener is not working. Do you know what is the Event, I should listen to catch before a new account is created ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind to all of the model internal events like this:

```
User::extend(function($model) {
    $model->bindEvent('model.beforeSave', function() use ($model) {
        // do something
    });
});
```

You can use `before` and `after` for `create`, `update`, `save`, `fetch` and `delete`

Comment: If he wants to restrict registration he should use the `beforeCreate` event not `beforeSave` - the latter will be fired before the model is saved, either created or updated

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use,

```
public function boot()
{
    User::creating(function($model) {
        var_dump($model->name);
    });
}
```

available events to listen:
`creating`, `created`, `updating`, `updated`, `deleting`, `deleted`, `saving`, `saved`, `restoring`, `restored`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following:

```
\Event::listen('eloquent.creating: RainLab\User\Models\User', function($user){
    $this->checkDomains($user);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to a Front-End User's registration ? - I assumed you're using the RainLab User Plugin which has an event `rainlab.user.beforeRegister` fired in the [Account component](https://github.com/rainlab/user-plugin/blob/master/components/Account.php#L219) or you can add a custom one in the model's `beforeCreate()` event

then simply create a `init.php` file in the root directory of your plugin and list your listeners there :

`Event::listen('rainlab.user.beforeRegister',   'Path\To\ListenersClass');`