# Laravel Ldaprecord with Spatie Roles - assign role after first login

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I was researching the case, but I couldn't find the right topic.

I use Ldaprecord along with Laravel Breeze to authenticate Users. On the very beginning database is empty, so after 1st login, User is added (imported) to DB.

But now I wanted to add Spatie Roles and assign a role and permission to the User who is signing into the application for the 1st time. How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Laravel events on user created, and then add role to user:

```php
$user->assignRole('writer');
```

You can use this on SO : [Listen to Event : User::creating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130701/listen-to-event-usercreating)

Laravel documentation about events will help you, or also LdapRecords documentation for events : https://ldaprecord.com/docs/core/v1/events/